# Sql time range count with average and formula

Tags: sql, postgresql

SQl query return the particular range of time values and count

```
select
res.range, count(*)
from (select 
CASE WHEN t1.response_time between 0 and 4 then 'Within 4 Hours' 
WHEN t1.response_time between 4 and 6 then '4-6 Hours' 
WHEN t1.response_time between 6 and 8 then '6-8 Hours'
WHEN t1.response_time > 8 then  '8+ Hours'
END as range
from table1 t1) as res
group by res.range
```

The below SQl query return the particular range of time values and count

```
   Range        | Count
 ----------------------
  4-6 Hours     |  24
  8+ Hours      |  23
  6-8 Hours     |  22
  Within 4 Hours|  7
```

Expected Output

```
  Range        | Count
----------------------
 4-6 Hours     |  24
 8+ Hours      |  23
 6-8 Hours     |  22
 Within 4 Hours|  7
 Average       |  x  (Average of Range Time Count)
```

In the range last row i want to shows the average and average range time count. How to display the last row average and also what is the formula for calculating Average of Range Time count.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgres? You tagged this with both

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select
res.range, count(*)
from (select 
CASE WHEN t1.response_time between 0 and 4 then 'Within 4 Hours' 
WHEN t1.response_time between 4 and 6 then '4-6 Hours' 
WHEN t1.response_time between 6 and 8 then '6-8 Hours'
WHEN t1.response_time > 8 then  '8+ Hours'
END as range
from table1 t1) as res
group by res.range
union all
select 'Average', AVG(counting) from
(
select
res.range, count(*) as counting
from (select 
CASE WHEN t1.response_time between 0 and 4 then 'Within 4 Hours' 
WHEN t1.response_time between 4 and 6 then '4-6 Hours' 
WHEN t1.response_time between 6 and 8 then '6-8 Hours'
WHEN t1.response_time > 8 then  '8+ Hours'
END as range
from table1 t1) as res
group by res.range
) t
```

Comment: it's a crying shame that MySQL doesn't support common table expressions

Comment: I have modified the code. Refer it and see if it works

Comment: thanks modified code working but in the above query i have extra one column row_number() over () as id. In the fifth row id start with 1 instead of 5.

Comment: Please see the below query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64011370/sql-extra-time-calculate-based-on-customer-plan-limit-and-sum-of-plan-used-past

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `with rollup` trick:

```
select coalesce(res.range, 'Total') as range, avg(cnt) as cnt
from (select res.range, count(*) as cnt
      from (select (CASE WHEN t1.response_time between 0 and 4 then 'Within 4 Hours' 
                         WHEN t1.response_time between 4 and 6 then '4-6 Hours' 
                         WHEN t1.response_time between 6 and 8 then '6-8 Hours'
                         WHEN t1.response_time > 8 then  '8+ Hours'
                    END) as range
           from table1 t1
          ) res
      group by res.range
     ) r
group by res.range with rollup;
```

The outer `group by` sort of does nothing for the existing rows -- the average of a single value is that value.  But it should the total line with the average.

Comment: Thanks for reply in postgresql how to use the same query

Comment: Please see the below query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64011370/sql-extra-time-calculate-based-on-customer-plan-limit-and-sum-of-plan-used-past